# Implement Displacement Mapping: Gaps along seams

Tags: graphics, directx, textures, directx-11

I am implementing Displacement mapping using DirectX 11 with its new tessellation stages.

Diffuse map and displacement map are generated by xNormal.

The result after I applied displacement mapping is cracked so badly. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeUDy.jpg

Then I realized the values in the texture along seams are not the same/continuous, so I just use diffuse texture as displacement map, and the diffuse color is all-red.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyXiJ.jpg

The result is better but still 1-pixel gap along the seams.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTzmS.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRNEg.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs7c8.jpg

I was confused by the little gap, so I enlarged the colored-part in the texture using MS painter, then the gap disappeared!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwXgn.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB8eu.jpg

Now I just don't understand where the problem is.
Even if the value along seams from different part of the texture is the same (red in this case),
there are still gaps on the result model.

I tried all sample filter [here(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but nothing helps.

What causes the gap? It will be better if the problem can be solved by just modifying texture instead of changing my code.

Comment: Do you use an indexed representation for your geometry or do you repeat some vertices in the vertex buffer? If the latter is the case, two identical vertices might be displaced with slightly different values due to floating point precision errors.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement watertight seam filtering :D
If not, those gaps appear because normals are different across UV seams.
Pretty obvious.